# Drag and Drop codeception

Tags: codeception

I'm running a test with codeception to do a `Drag & Drop`. Running the test returns no error BUT the `Drag & Drop` does not actually work (I don't see what I want).
I have to move one window to another

This is my test:

```php
$I->click(['id' => 'showGallery']); 
$I->amOnUrl("http://xxxxxx");
$I->dragAndDrop("//div[@class='grid-stack-item-content']","//div[@id='dashboard']");
$I->wait ('15');
$I->see ("Codice prodotto:");
```

This is my `acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://xxxx
            host: xxxx
            port: xxxx
            window_size: false
            browser: chrome
            capabilities:
              unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'ignore'
              chromeOptions:
                args: ["--disable-gpu", "window-size=1920x1080", "--no-sandbox"]
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```